# Как подключить БД из phpMyAdmin к Python 3-x?

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть база данных в phpMyAdmin, в phpMyAdmin я захожу с помощью включенного Danwer.

Пытался подключить через библиотеку pypyodbc, но не подключалось:

> (pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов
>   ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по
>   умолчанию')).

Как подключить?

Answer (score 0):

База данных у Вас какая ? MySQL ?
Импортируйте библиотеку pymysql.
Попробуйте создать подключение вида :
db = pymysql.connect(host='ip_адрес_сервера', user='имя_пользователя', passwd='пароль', db='имя_базы', charset='utf8')
создайте обьект курсора 
cursor = db.cursor()
И делайте запрос к базе 
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM название_таблицы ')
Закрываем подключение 
db.close()